# Why is the law of large numbers used in Bayesian statistics?

Tags: bayesian

Bayesians believe that we should hold a belief of values and NOT focus on the long-term frequency of some value.

If this premise is true, why do Bayesians insist use MCMC to approximate the posterior using an infinity number of MCMC samples if they don't believe in the law of large numbers? Why don't they hold a belief of the number of iterations to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bayesians are often less concerned with the asymptotic properties of certain estimators than frequentists. This is a result of interpreting inference differently rather than not believing in the law of large numbers. The law can be proved and "not believing it" would not be sensible.

The Bayesian approach to statistics does indeed suggest that we should hold a belief about an unknown state of the world. If the belief is a probability distribution, we can summarise the distribution by considering samples drawn from the distribution. Approximating (some property of) a distribution by sampling it has nothing to do with being Bayesian or frequentist; it is simply a useful tool of probability theory. The approximations become better as we draw more samples.